# powershell script calling another script reading excel fails

Tags: excel, powershell

only new to PowerShell so I hope someone can help me with my little issue.

I've written a script that accepts 2 parameters and opens and reads an excel file (lets call it `excelRead.ps1`). When I execute this by itself everything works fine.

However, when I call `excelRead.ps1` from inside another script the code to open the excel file appears to fail with absolutely no error.

e.g.

```
. c:\runIt.ps1 -ws "valid - 20140528" -out "$out_file"
```

Anyone have any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Comment: How do you call excelRead.ps1?

Answer (score 0):

Personally one of the three things I load in my sessions anytime I launch powershell is a script that loads 1 function: Import-Xls (by Francis de la Cerna). ([Get it here!](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/17bcabe7-322a-43d3-9a27-f3f96618c74b)) Which really brings me to my point, (which I think was a *Hey, Scripting Guy!* blog a long time ago): Don't write scripts, write functions.

This would probably be simpler if you wrote your 'other script' as a function that could be called upon, and then run in the context of the current scope. For example, if you had the Import-Xls.ps1 file in the current path you could do something like:

```
. .\Import-Xls.ps1
$Data = Import-Xls <path to .XLS(x) file> -Worksheet "valid - 20140528"
```

Then you have the data from that sheet stored in `$Data` to do with as you please.